# Fancybox visibility problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

When setting a style at #inline2 hiding it, Fancybox will appear empty on click. In addition the #inline2 element can be seen in Fancybox when there's no style hiding it. Though this example is copy'ed directly from the various examples on the official Fancybox site. See Various Examples at http://fancybox.net/home.

Someone please enlighten me, and tell me what I'm doing wrong! I obviously only want the #inline2 element to be shown in Fancybox, and not as a regular part of my page.

Thanks in advance

/The guy having spend hours on what should be an easy job!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html lang="da">
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#various2").fancybox({
   'modal' : true,
   'transitionIn' : 'fade',
   'transitionOut' : 'fade'
  });
 });
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a id="various2" href="#inline2">Inline - modal window</a>
    <div id="inline2" style="display:none;">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry all, seems I got my code pasted wrong. Please see for full code view: http://pastie.org/1031860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at [this example](http://fancybox.net/howto), it becomes obvious that you have to point the `href` of the anchor element to a `div` *within* another one with `style="display:none"` (see #4), so you shouldn't put the actual contents within a `div` with `display:none`, otherwise the contents will remain hidden (as you can see in Firebug).

Change your code to

```
<div style="display:none"><div id="inline2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div></div>
```

BTW, there are some errors within your page, like the closing tag `</a>` in `#inline2`, and some others. When your page is rendered using an XML parser, your users will only see a (probably yellow) error page.

Comment: You are right. I was looking at the example proved at the frontpage, just copy'ing the way they did. Strange.

I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assign id `inline2` to the `p` element

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <p id="inline2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        adipiscing elit. &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

If you want your XHTML to validate as well, you have to

- Change `<html lang="da">` to `<html lang="da" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.
- Close the meta element properly `/>`.
- Add a title for your document.
- Enclose the hyperlink in a block element.
- Remove the extra `</a>` in your `p` element.